# Who is this figure of an orange-haired schoolgirl?

Tags: merchandise

I got her from a mystery bag. Anybody has any idea who this character is?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Anime: *Food Wars!: Shokugeki no Soma*

Character: Erina Nakiri

Here is the anime scene which resembles the figure in the photo.

[image: scene from anime which resembles the figure]

Answer (score 1):

Erina Nakiri from *Food Wars*. Figured it out.